# Jersey Client API already JAX-RS 2.0 aware?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Does the current Jersey Client API already implement the JAX-RS 2.0 Client API or are these independent attempts of jersey?

I had a look in the last Early Draft Review of JAx-RS 2.0 and the Client Api attempts seem similar to jersey ones. Don't get me wrong - I know that jersey is the reference implementation. I was just wondering if jersey implements in version 2.0 the new jax-rs 2.0 client api or if it's already done or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey 1 = JAX-RS 1, Jersey 2 = JAX-RS 2.

From the Jersey 2 status page - "more than half of Jersey 1.x proprietary API's becomes part of JAX-RS in version 2.0" (but with some changes - disclaimer is mine)

Comment: Ok, but seems that there is no clear statement about the client api.

Comment: Jersey 1 had a Jersey specific client API. It is what the JAX-RS 2.0 client API was based on. The client API in Jersey 2 is the now standardized JAX-RS 2 client API (which isn't final yet).

Comment: Are you sure about that fact: The JAX-RS 2 Client API is based on Jersey 1, so the Jersey 2.0 doesnt need to implement a new one, its just about some changes. Can I somewhere read about this?

Comment: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/2.0-m04/migration.html
You can also look at the history of the Jersey code to see how it has evolved with the updates to the spec. https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClient.java (look at history)